# My kitten won't stop biting

Tags: cats, training, biting

He is about 3 to 4 months old. I read that kittens can start biting when they start getting their permanent teeth but he bites all the time. We play with toys and I let him bite them but he keeps biting me and other people. Even when I'm sitting still and don't look like "prey" he'll jump at me and start biting down and sometimes it really hurts.

I've done a lot of things I've read online like clapping my hands, transferring his attention to a toy, and becoming still so you become boring for your cat to play with but I think being still when you're cat has attacked while you were still is just telling your cat it's ok to keep biting. Nothing is working. He'll bite hands, elbows, clothes, feet, toes, everything. I'll try to keep them out of his reach but he will jump and get it. He knows he shouldn't though because sometimes when he starts biting softly, I make a slight hissing noise and he immediately starts to lick instead. Then goes back to biting.

Also he sometimes starts to bite himself when I tell to stop like he's throwing a tantrum. Like "No! I'm going to bite and if I can't bite you, I'm going to bite myself!".

Is this a phase the he will grow out of, or is he just a biter?

How can I make him stop?

Comment: i gave an answer on how to change the behaviour of cats over here https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18252/what-should-i-do-to-discourage-my-cat-from-slapping-me a few days ago maby take a look there.the answer i gave is maby not the best but it is an answer.

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry it's a duplicate question. Its just I've tried everything and nothing has worked. Maybe I should just accept his biting like one commenter has said on the thread you linked. I would try not to mind or try to evade his attacks but it hurts and he's very quick. Oh well.

Comment: you simply have to make the biting stop,the cat is small now but it will soon be an adult cat and beeing bitten by a adult cat is something else than by a kitten,take a look in the related questions hopefully you will find something usefull there.